# 'Juggling' with commutators, and how this gives the identities I wanna have

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is part of a proof from Kurzweil/Stellmacher: *Theory of Finite Groups*, chapter 5.3. For a $p$-group $G$ set
$$
 \Omega(G) := \langle x \in G : x^p = 1 \rangle.
$$
i.e. the subgroup generated by the element having order $p$.

> Let $x,y \in P$ elements of a $p$-group $P$, and let
>   $$
>  [x,y] \in \Omega(Z(P)).
> $$
>   a) If $p \ne 2$, then $(xy)^p = x^p y^p$.
>
> b) If $p = 2$, then $(xy)^2 = x^2 y^2[x,y]$ and $(xy)^4 = x^4y^4$.
>
> *Proof:* Set $z := [x,y]$. Then $x^y = xz$ and $x^{y^i} = xz^i$ for $i \ge 1$. The hypothesis implies that $z^p = 1$, and thus
>   $$
>  (x^p)^y = (x^y)^p = x^p z^p = x^p. \quad (*)
> $$
>   Set $p = 2$. Then
>   $$
>  (xy)^2 = xyxy = xy^2x[x,y] = x^2 y^2 z,
> $$
>   and $(xy)^4 = x^2 y^2 z x^2 y^2 z = x^4 y^4$.
>   If $p \ne 2$, then
>   \begin{align*}
>  (xy^{-1})^p & = (xy^{-1})(xyy^{-2})(xy^2y^{-3})\cdots (xy^{p-1}y^p) \\
>              & = x xz xz^2 \cdots xz^{p-1} y^{-p} \\
>              & = (x^p y^{-p})(z z^2 \cdots z^{p-1}).
> \end{align*}
>   Since
>   $$
>  zz^2 \cdots z^{p-1} = z^{\frac{p(p-1)}{2}} = 1
> $$
>   (a) follows.

My question: How did (a) follows when they just show it for the inverse $y^{-1}$, i.e. $(xy^{-1})^p = x^p y^{-p}$ instead of $(xy)^p = x^p y^p$? In many cases, as inversion gives a bijection it indeed does not matter if we show an identity with the inverse, but here $[x,y^{-1}] \ne [x,y]$ in general, and I do not see that $[x,y^{-1}] \in \Omega(Z(P))$ is equivalent to $[x,y] \in \Omega(Z(P))$? Also why has he shown (*), I do not see how it is related to the assertions proven?

All the other parts of the proof I understand (I think). We have $x^{y^i} = xz^i$ because $x^{yy} = (x^y)^y = (xz)^y = x^y z^y = (xz)z^y = xz^2$ as conjugation is an automorphism and $z \in Z(P)$. Also in (*) he uses that $x$ and $z$ commute. And the last sequence of equations is best seen by computing an example
$$
 (xy^{-1})(xyy^{-2})(xy^2y^{-3})
  = xx[x,y]x[x,y^2]y^{-3}
$$
where $[x,y^2] = [x,y][x,y]^y = z^2$ and so this equals $xxzxz^2y^{-3}$. So this is my understanding. Hoping someone could explain the points I do not understand!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is relation between commutator $[x,y]$ and $[x,y^{-1}]$? According to notation in book you mentioned, $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$. Then 
$$[x,y^{-1}]=x^{-1}yxy^{-1}=(yx^{-1}y^{-1}x)^{-1}=(y.x^{-1}y^{-1}xy.y^{-1})^{-1}$$
(in last equality, inserted $y$ and $y^{-1}$ at end.)
This last expression is $(y.[x,y].y^{-1})^{-1}$, so 
$$[x,y^{-1}]=(y.[x,y].y^{-1})^{-1}.$$
Now $\Omega(Z(G))$ is a subgroup, it is closed under inverse, hence 
$$[x,y^{-1}]=(y.[x,y].y^{-1})^{-1} \in \Omega(Z(G)) \Longleftrightarrow y.[x,y].y^{-1} \in \Omega(Z(G)).$$
Next, $\Omega(Z(G))$ is normal, hence 
$$y.[x,y].y^{-1} \in \Omega(Z(G)) \Longleftrightarrow [x,y]\in \Omega(Z(G)).$$

(I hope, this much answer you wanted; if something more you expect, let me know.)